# Finding header of webpage selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm written a test which i'm now trying to enhance and make it do more things.

I understand how to find a title of a webpage by using the following code

```
String title = webDriver.Title;
```

But if i now want to also output the header of the page how would i go about doing this? 
This is the web URL: https://energy.gocompare.com/gas-electricity#/
I've found the element: Switch today and save on your energy bills

Can i use an **XPath** to find this? then `Console.WriteLine` the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **code** :

```
String element = webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.c-header__heading")).Text;
Console.WriteLine("This is the text extracted from " +element);
```

XPATH :

```
//h1[@class='c-header__heading']
```

In code, you can use it like :

```
String someText= webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h1[@class='c-header__heading']")).Text;
Console.WriteLine("This is the text extracted from " +someText);
```

Comment: Can i create a loop so that it validates the output of the header.  String header =webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("h1.c-header__heading")).Text;
            
            if(header.Contains(header))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("jriofjio");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("incorrect");
            }

Comment: No need to use loop , if you have only one text. Did that work for you ?